# Rename ec2 hostname using userdata does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

I am trying to rename the hostname to a specific one - `TEAM-CNTNR` using the user-data script but after the EC2 instance comes up online and I connect to it (via Session Manager), the hostname is the random one that EC2 service gives the instance such as `EC2AMAZ-VHAGRNV`.

This is my user-data script, am I missing something? This is my user-data script:

```
<powershell>
Import-Module ECSTools

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ECS_ENABLE_AWSLOGS_EXECUTIONROLE_OVERRIDE", $TRUE, "Machine")
Initialize-ECSAgent -Cluster "${cluster_name}" -EnableTaskIAMRole -LoggingDrivers '["json-file","awslogs"]' -EnableTaskENI

# rename the instance hostname so that it works with the gMSA account
Rename-Computer -NewName "TEAM-CNTNR" -Force

## instance-domain-join code here. Omitted for brevity

# Perform the domain join
Add-Computer -DomainName "$domain_name.$domain_tld" -OUPath "OU=Computers,OU=enrcloud,DC=enr,DC=cloud" -ComputerName "$hostname" -Credential $credential -Passthru -Verbose -Restart
</powershell>
<runAsLocalSystem>true</runAsLocalSystem>
```

Comment: Did the VM become joined in the domain? Did the computer account exist already?

Comment: Hi, yes - the domain join code worked fine before I added the hostname change code line

Answer (score 0):

It was revealed to me that there is a `NewName` parameter that can be used that is part of the `Add-Computer` command that would:

- join the machine to the new domain
- and change its name at the same time

```
Add-Computer ... -NewName "MyComputer" ...
```

Reference: [Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-computer?view=powershell-5.1#example-7--move-a-computer-to-a-new-domain-and-change-the-name-of-the-computer)